# DatePicker Renderer to change textcolor if not selecting the datepicker field

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

I  changed the datepicker textcolor white to red when the datepicker field is not selected by the user.But after that when user select the datepicker field i want to change the textcolor to white.But the text color remains the red color.

By default my xmal page datepicker textcolor is white.How to change the color to white after the red color.

how to add datepicker to placeholder property?

I want to remove the default value of date picker control when the  page is loading.How to solve this problem.
when loading the page current date is in the date picker field.i don't want to set the default date.

how to set blank date on datepicker control in xamarin forms

```
dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

dtpDate.CustomFormat = " ";

i found a solution like the above code.But its not working